# kpm restore unable to find System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

Doing some work with Docker, trying to create an ASP.NET 5 container but when it gets to restoring packages, kpm returns OK for everything except:

```
Unable to locate System.Net.Http
```

I've also tried swapping this with Microsoft.Net.Http.Client but get a similar response.

This is my project.json file:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot"
    ],
    "packExclude": [
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0.0-beta2-10877",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0.0-beta2-11936",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0.0-beta2-12332",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0.0-beta1-10525",
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY /app/approot/src/Docker.Web /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["kpm", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["k", "kestrel"]
```

I just need access to a WebClient or similar, am I going about it the correct way?

**UPDATE**

OK I am pretty sure it's related to the NuGet source I'm pointing at. I tried updating kpm restore to use the MyGet aspnetrelease feed instead. Existing problem is fixed but now I get:

```
Unable to locate Newtonsoft.Json >= 6.0.6
```

Aaaaaaaaaaaaargh

Changed my Dockerfile RUN command to:

```
RUN ["kpm", "restore", "-s", "https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to updating stuff with kpm, I had to add this file (NuGet.Config):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

To `/root/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config`. Since it's Linux, case matters for the file path and the filename.

Comment: Thanks! What does root refer to? Application root or system root?

Comment: Sorry, the root directory when using the official vNext Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Success!

Updated Dockerfile RUN command to:

```
RUN ["kpm", "restore", "-s", "https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v2", "-f", "https://nuget.org/api/v2"]
```

This sets default to the aspnetrelease MyGet feed with a fallback to NuGet.

One thing to note: Updating this command and running on the same Docker host didn't work and returned a really weird Linux error. I deleted and recreated the Docker host, built my image again and it worked finally.

Hopefully this helps someone else in future.